# Can't start Stable Diffusion on Google Colab

Tags: python, google-chrome

I don’t understand how to fix this error, it just doesn’t want to start

I tried to re-login to Google Drive, restart again, but I'm afraid to get into the code because I don't know python, and maybe something is missing:

Screen1:

[image]

Screen2:

[image]

Screen3:

[image]